# Transmitting integer values between two sockets c++

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp

I have a c++ socket program where there are two processes. The server process and client process. The client registers with the server and listens on a port for any message from server.

I have defined a "char *buffer" which will have my message. The message size is say 59000 Bytes. Now before transmitting the message i am adding the message size at the beginning of the buffer,

```
size=htonl(59000)
Buffer= size + <Actual Message>
```

so that client process when ever it gets a message it reads first two bytes to get size first, knows the size of message transmitted and then it reads the complete message from the socket. This is done as below

```
59000 in binary format is          00000000 00000000 11100110 01111000  
htonl(59000) in binary format is   01111000 11100110 00000000 00000000
```

I used memcpy to copy this size to charcter buffer.

```
memcpy(buffer, &size, 4) <since size of int is 4>
```

After transmitting the message at client when i read the first two bytes i get the size as zero. But if i read the next two bytes i get the correct size that is 59000. The way i am reading the message size at client is as mentioned below

```
int messageSize=0;
memcpy(&messageSize, buffer, 2 );
```

Can some one please explain me why the message size is stored in the second two bytes and not in the first two bytes.

I would be very grateful to you if you can help me. I have been trying to understand this from quite some time.

Comment: Maybe you should send the whole `int`.

Comment: I like your style of explaining. However, I still need to see the actual source code, or I can't spot the bug. Sorry. Just paste it and surround it with <code> tags or just indent it four spaces.

Comment: Or, lol you could do what the other commenter said. What is `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: You actually memcpy four bytes when preparing to send - so seem to know how many bytes htonl returns - but you talk about reading just 2 bytes....!

Comment: Why do you care about individual bytes and two-byte chunks? You have ints. Work with ints and sizeof(int)-sized chunks (don't use 4 or 2 or whatever, use sizeof(yourtype)).

Comment: Hi All,
Thanks for your replies. i dont have control over the receiving end. It is hard coded at the receiving end that it will read the first two bytes for getting the size of message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one serious mistake in your explanation :

```
59000 in binary format is          00000000 00000000 11100110 01111000  
htonl(59000) in binary format is   01111000 11100110 00000000 00000000
```

is wrong it really is the ohter way around so

```
59000 in binary format is          01111000 11100110 00000000 00000000
htonl(59000) in binary format is   00000000 00000000 11100110 01111000
```

that is this is the case on cpu that is little endian.
So since a int is 4 bytes, this perfectly explains why you receive 2 zero bytes first.

htonl stands for host to network long. host order is the ordering of the bytes on the host. This can be different on little and big endian machines, but network order is well defined and it must be because otherwise computers could not talk to eachother.

There is also htons: for short
and the reverse of htons and htonl is ntohl and ntohs

These functions do the exact same thing as their counterparts, that is in a big endian system they don't do anything at all, in little endian they reverse the byte order of whatever comes in. 
htons(htons(x)) does nothing. There is no way to detect for the computer if a value is byte reversed. use ntohl and ntohs when coming from network order to host order, you'll need this at the client when you receive the first 4 bytes and want to know the length.

Answer (score 0):

`htonl` converts a long (meaning 4-byte int) from host-byte-order to network-byte-order. Network-byte-order is defined as big-endian, that is the most significant byte of a multi-byte number is first. The host-byte-order is either big-endian (in which case `htonl` does nothing) or little-endian (in which case `htonl` reverses the bytes).

In all cases, the bytes representing `59000` will be transmitted as `0x00 0x00 0xe6 0x78`. So if you only read the first two bytes, you will always get `0x00 0x00`. To read the value correctly on all systems, you need to read all four bytes into a 32-bit integer, and then call `ntohl` to convert the number from network-byte-order to host-byte-order.